# Modules not loading react-native dependencies

Tags: android, react-native

Does anyone know why some of my third party packages won't load com.facebook.react.modules.core.*? The core folder is a sibling of the bridge components so I am confused as to why it is not loading the core folder that contains PermissionListener and PermissionAwareActivity.

[image: CMD error]

I was able to fix this single package manually by changing the individual build.gradle that came with the package but the error also came up with the next package it loaded.  This lets me know that its not a problem with the individual package itself but maybe the root error is related to my environment or base project.  I am running on React-Native 0.45.1, and my problem third party modules are react-native-image-crop-picker and react-native-notifications if that helps.

Comment: have u linked ur modules correctly using react-native link {module name}

Comment: Yes I have, I used the react-native link command and I also followed the individual instructions that was listed with all the individual modules from their documentation

Comment: can u share which 3rd party modules u r using?

Comment: I updated the question